# What is the proper way to activate jQuery validation on a form that was loaded via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-validate, buddypress

I have a WordPress/BuddyPress registration form, and I want to handle the form submission via an Ajax call, rather than direct page submission.  I have the following code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setupValidation();
});

function setupValidation()
{
jQuery("#signup_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        jQuery("#signup_submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        jQuery(".form-actions").html('<img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" /> Processing...'); 

        jQuery.post('<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>', jQuery("#signup_form").serialize(), function(data) {

            var response = jQuery(data).find('#signup_form');

            if( jQuery(response).length )
            {
                jQuery('#signup_form').html(response);

                setupValidation();
            }
            else
            {
                    alert("Form submitted.");
                top.location = self.location.href;
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Basically, what this is doing is submitting the form data via ajax, and then checking the response to see if there are errors.  If there are errors, I want to replace the old form HTML with the response HTML so as to show any error messages along with the original form.

The problem I am experiencing is that although the validation handles the initial form functioning properly, when there is an error and the form is reloaded, the validation is not initialized.  Instead, in the console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

This error is repeated each time a field on the ajax loaded form is clicked or focused.  Also, the submitHandler doesn't seem to work the second time around, and the form simply submits the old fashioned way.  (no ajax)

Any help with this would be most appreciated.  It seems like there's just something simple I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it is.  All I want to do is re-initialize the validation code on a form that was loaded via ajax.

Thanks in advance,
James.

Comment: You're calling `setupValidation` from within the `submitHandler` which is part of `.validate()` which is already inside of `setupValidation`...  see the issue here?  `.validate()` is the _initialization_ method and only needs to be called _once_.  There is no practical point to calling it again on the same form and since the `submitHandler` only fires on a valid form, there is absolutely no use in calling it from inside of itself.

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"Basically, what this is doing is submitting the form data via ajax, and then checking the response to see if there are errors. If there are errors, I want to replace the old form HTML with the response HTML so as to show any error messages along with the original form."_ ~ Let me get this straight... if client-side validation gives an error, you want server-side validation to give the error messages?  This makes no sense.

Comment: Where is the code that corresponds to the title of the thread?  In other words, where is the ajax that loads the form?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the form entirely, with a new set of HTML, why not just reset the form?

If the response contains an important message in addition to the form, perhaps just return the message and stick that somewhere within the form...

```
        if( jQuery(response).length )
        {
            //jQuery('#signup_form').html(response);
            jQuery('#messages').html(response);//would need to create a div with id of "messages"

            jQuery('#signup_form').data('validator').resetForm();
            jQuery('#signup_form').get(0).reset();

        }
```